# Examples for combinatorial explosion in Java?

Tags: java, effective-java

In the Effective Java, Item - 18, Bloch says that interfaces prevent combinatorial explosion, which will happen when using abstract classes with multiple attributes in a type system.

I am not able to wrap my head around what exactly is combinatorial explosion.

Can anyone provide an example of combinatorial explosion because of using abstract classes, and how interfaces are used to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: This answer borrows from [Software Architecture Design Patterns in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0849321425), see the Decorator pattern chapter for an example of combinatorial explosion.

Suppose you have a `Logger` interface, and three concrete implementations: `FileLogger`, `STDOUTLogger`, `DBLogger`. Now imagine that there are 3 possible formats in which a line can be logged: `Plain`, `HTML`, `Encrypted`.

Naively one can create a class for each of the possible combinations, which total `3 * 3 = 9`:

1. `FileLoggerPlain`
2. `FileLoggerHtml`
3. `FileLoggerEncrypt`
4. `STDOUTLoggerPlain`
5. `STDOUTLoggerHtml`
6. `STDOUTLoggerEncrypt`
7. `DBLoggerPlain`
8. `DBLoggerHtml`
9. `DBLoggerEncrypt`

The 9 above translate to 9 types in Java. Notice the proliferation of classes that has resulted to support each combination. You can instead create reusable types to describe the logger medium (File, STDOUT, DB), and the format (Plain, Html, Encrypt). Notice this results in 6 types only. You can then use patterns like Decorator to wrap a logger type in a format type (E.g. `EncryptLoggerDecorator` wraps `DBLogger`, or wraps `STDOUTLogger`) to dynamically alter behavior of a system, as opposed to statically defining the behavior if you were to use a bloated class hierarchy. I believe the point that Joshua Bloch tries to drive home is to keep hierarchies flat, and Java interfaces lend themselves well for that purpose.

Comment: Or one can use composition: a Logger class, with two fields, something like: `LogFormatter` (would be one of `PlainFormatter` and `HtmlFormatter` and `EncryptedFormatter`) plus `LogWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

> If there are n attributes in the type system, there are 2n possible
>   combinations that you might have to support. This is what’s known as a
>   combinatorial explosion. Bloated class hierarchies can lead to bloated
>   classes containing many methods that differ only in the type of their
>   argu- ments, as there are no types in the class hierarchy to capture
>   common behaviors.

One of the big disadvantages of abstract classes compared to interfaces that you can't extend multiple classes.

For example with interfaces you can do

```
public interface Singer {
 AudioClip Sing(Song s);
}

public interface Songwriter {
 Song compose(boolean hit):
}

public interface SingerSongwriter extends Singer, Songwriter 
{ 
 AudioClip strum(); 
 void actSensitive();
}
```

With abstract classes you should do something like this:

```
public abstract class Singer {
 abstract AudioClip Sing(Song s);
}

public abstract class Songwriter {
 abstract  Song compose(boolean hit):
}

public abstract class SingerSongwriter extends Singer 
{ 
 abstract  AudioClip strum(); 
 abstract  void actSensitive();
 abstract  Song compose(boolean hit):
}
```

With abstract classes you have `Song compose(boolean hit)` duplicated and support of this code is much difficult. This system is not so robust as with interface using.